# Getting Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>' when trying to produce a feed

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-listview, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to retrieve a feed from Firestore, then build Widgets and present them in a ListView wrapped in a `FutureBuilder`.
Unfortunately, I keep getting this error:

```
E/flutter (20020): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'
E/flutter (20020): #0      _MomentsFeedState.getWidgetList (package:buzz/moments/moment_feed.dart:78:40)
E/flutter (20020): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Here is my function to retrieve data:

```dart
  Stream<List<String>> getFriendUUIDS() => Firestore.friends
    .doc(gameManager.myself.uuid)
    .snapshots()
    .map((snapshot) => ((snapshot.data()?.keys)?.toList()) ?? []);

  Future<List<MomentWidget>> getWidgetList() async{
    List<MomentWidget> widgetList = [];
    Set<String> momentIds = Set();
    await for (final uuids in getFriendUUIDS()){
      for (String uuid in uuids){
        DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> values =  await Firestore.users
        .doc(uuid)
        .get();
        for (String momentId in values.data()?['moments']){
          debugPrint('momentId: $momentId');
          momentIds.add(momentId);
        }
      }
    }
    
    for (String momentId in momentIds){
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> values = 
      await Firestore.instance.collection('moments').doc(momentId).get();
      Map<String, dynamic>? data = values.data()!;
      String downloadURL = await storage.ref('moments/$momentId').getDownloadURL();
      MomentWidget widget = MomentWidget(numLikes: data['liked_by'].length ,
       location: data['location'],
        date: data['timestamp'],
        names: data['taggedFriends'].toString(),
        shotBy: data['taken_by'], image: NetworkImage(downloadURL));
      widgetList.add(widget);
    }
    return widgetList;
  }
```

And the function to build the feed:

```
Widget feed(){
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      height: size.height,
      width: size.width,
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getWidgetList(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<MomentWidget>> snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemBuilder: (context, pos) {
                      return snapshot.data![pos];
                    },
                  );
              }
            default:
              return Text('Unhandled State');
          }
        }
      ),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getWidgetList();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: feed(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get no output to the screen. I am new to Flutter so I'm not sure if I'm making some other type of error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `moments` can be null but there is no check about it. In the for loop use a null-coalescing operator `??` to default to an empty list if `moments` is null.

It's going to be like the following snippet:

```dart
for (String momentId in values.data()?['moments'] ?? []){
  debugPrint('momentId: $momentId');
  momentIds.add(momentId);
}
```